# Unity New Input system: Mouse click (Any button) not working keyboard is working fine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i can't detect the mouse click of any button when i am using new input system, same code is working when i use keybaord button (Any). i am using unity defualt events for calling functions.
[my input action assest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnlvj.png) as you can see it is set on button.
[my Input Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDjmo.png) my USB cable mouse by A4tech is showing up in unspported devices at first i thought that can be the issue, but the problem is even built-in tarackpad mouse of my laptop is not working.

```
 public void PrintVal(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
        {
            if (context.performed)
            {
                Debug.Log("testing");
            }
        }
```

this is the test code i am calling using unity default event system. i am trying to swtich my game to new input system  because i am planing to release my game for both pc and mobile devices but i gotta say new input is kinda of a mess. **PLEASE SOMEONE HELP ME WHAT IS GOING ON HERE**
[Unity events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWkAv.png)

i tried many different way button, value, vector 2 even tho does not make sense tried same thing with keyboard input worked.

Comment: ive never done it by UI but by code when you bring in the input, and link up the events you need to enable the input.. is there any chance some of this hasnt happened? Have you tried by code?

Comment: yes tried bu code using generator c# class still not working, input debugger is not detecting mouse clicks too i guess it has something to do with mouse support or something.

Comment: what generator c# if you mean generating the one in the input designer, no, i mean link your methods to the actions in code..

Comment: I am linking it through code too, 
`private void Start()
        {
            playerInput.Player.MouseClick.performed += ctx => PrintVal();
        }

        private void OnEnable()
        {
            playerInput.Enable();
        }

        private void OnDisable()
        {
            playerInput.Disable();
        }`

like this, but still not working besides it is not the issue with the code, the input debugger should catch you clicking the button press, even that is not registering the mouse clicks, it is showing me keyboard keys just not mouse ones.

Comment: ok then that does seem odd and maybe mouse driver related but it does sound/feel like theres some step missing, does Mouse.current work?

Comment: another development, the mouse is working fine in another project that I created. weird. i think it's a unity issue. i just switched my input system in project settings to new just now let me see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, I had "stimulate touch screen with mouse" turned on in the debugger, it turns out that when you turn that on mouse won't respond because it will act as a touch screen for even running the code like "mouse left button" you have to turn it off or use Touch press or Tap functionality.
[Input Debuuger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IqXo.png). So basically my understanding of the new input system was and still is weak my bad sorry.